# Check $post->ID against multiple values

Tags: php, posts

i have the following snippet on the site which is working perfectly fine but sometimes I have multiple pages where I want to trigger the event snippet from google, my questions can I add multiple ids using comma?

this is the code I am using which is working fine.

```
<?php if( $post->ID == 13052) { ?>
<!-- Event snippet for thank-you page --><script>  gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-105871269/5v9gsts6dbdsJ-Kl'});</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a PHP question than specifically Wordpress, but you can use PHP's `in_array` to test if `$post->ID` is in a bunch of values, like this:

```
    <?php if( in_array($post->ID, [13052, 1234, 4242]) ) { ?>
    <!-- Event snippet for thank-you page --><script>  gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-105871269/5v9gsts6dbdsJ-Kl'});</script>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: thank you and it worked perfectly :)